# How can stop a container div allowing contents to overflow?

Tags: html, css

Ok, quick ficticious example:

```
<div style="background: #CCC; margin: 10px;">
<div style="width: 50%; height: 400px; background: #FFF;">Child #1</div>
<div style="width: 600px; height: 400px; background: #999;">Child #2</div>
</div>
```

If I resize the browser to less than 600px wide (child #2), how can I stop the parent div from keeping on shrinking to the browser window (and shrinking child #1 in the process).

In essence how can I prevent a container div from shrinking any further when it hits the widest child inside itself?

Contents are dynamic so cannot specify widths of children, I just set the width of child #2 to illustrate the issue. It's the same if there were any element of specific width (e.g. an image or fully shrunken table etc.)

Answer (score 2):

I am not 100% sure what you are trying to do with your webpage by allowing the outer elements to expand and contract but forcing the innards to set sizes, but the first thing I would suggest is to set the `min-width` css attribute on your outer div.  The problem you will run into doing this is that you now have specified the same value in two different places (which for css2 is just a way of life).

To my knowledge there is no css attribute to limit the width of a parent to the size of its children.  You could replace the outer div with a table if that functionality is absolutely necessary, but it is probably a better idea to re-evaluate your design.  Perhaps if you could lay out a few more specifics of why this is necessary we could assist further.

Based on your comments, you could try something like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Hi</title>
  </head>
  <body style="margin: 0; padding:0;">
    <table style="background: red;padding:100px;width:100%;" cellspacing="0"><tr><td>
    <table style="background: #CCC; width:100%;border:none;" cellspacing="0"><tr><td>
        <div style="width: 50%; height: 400px; background: #FFF;">Child #1</div>
        <div style="width: 600px; height: 400px; background: #999;">Child #2</div>
    </td></tr></table>
    </td></tr></table>
  </body>
</html>
```

The reason you must have nested tables is because the outside table lets you control the margin/padding of what would otherwise be the html or body tags.  When you apply margin to body it does not affect the width of the page, and you always end up with a scroll bar across the bottom.  Nesting the tables and letting the outside table mimic it using padding solves the issue.  (Other people could probably come up with a more elegant solution)

That being said, if your container div is just setting the background color, you could just set the background color of the screen.  If your web page is left justified (something my designer friends would shoot me for), the browser window would handle the effect for you.

Comment: Well basically this is a simple container div which holds all the main content for the site. I don't want this container div to shrink any further than the widest element inside it (whatever that may be). Allowing this will further reduce other elements inside the conatiner of variable width. if you C&P this html and try it out in a browser I don't want the light grey to shrink further than the dark grey (yet I don't know what the dark grey width might be in any one particular case).

Comment: I guess I'm asking something more a long the lines of, "can you explain why it is important for your case to let the container resize while parts of the content are fixed".  I know what you're trying to do, but if I understand what it is you are trying to achieve by doing it, there might be a better way.

Comment: Well imagine a standard left menu / right content scenario. The things put inside the content are varied and there's no way to tell what's in it in a controlled way (dynamic content). So I was trying to have the container not have any of the contents overflow. I don't want to hide the overflow I just don't want the container to shrink past the widest of it's children if that makes any sense. So basically you'd have to scroll the browser sideways to see it (like say with a big image). Effectively I want to set a kind of min-width for the container depending on it's widest child which is unkown.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by NickLarsen's thoughtful and complete answer: try `display: table-cell` on your container.

Comment: Problem here is that this will not allow the container to expand further than the widest child. Also this won't work in ie7/6.